# Could not able to Pull the Docker Image of Red Hat Linux's JBoss EAP 7.2 from registry.redhat.io

Tags: image, docker, jboss, rhel

I need to pull the Red Hat Linux's JBoss EAP 7.2 Docker Image from registry.redhat.io .

When I logged into registry.redhat.io by providing the credentials, I got the below successful login message.

```
$ docker login registry.redhat.io

Authenticating with existing credentials...
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in C:\Users\srikanth.ganji.docker\config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded.
```

When I tried to pull the Dockerfile for Red Hat Linux's JBoss EAP 7.1 from registry.redhat.io, I have got the below issue

```
$ docker pull jboss-eap-7/eap72-openshift

Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for jboss-eap-7/eap72-openshift, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 docker pull registry.connect.redhat.com/jboss-eap-7/eap72-openshift
```

In docker when no base registry path is added at the beginning it goes to the official docker registry